# SQL Server 2012 - Bulk insert error - This operation conflicts with another pending operation on this transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

We are doing a bulk insert operation using a C# component.

This is the code:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SET XACT_ABORT ON", _sqlConnection))
{
    sqlCommand.SafeExecuteNonQuery();
}

var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_sqlConnection, bulkCopyOptions, null);

sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
```

The following error occurs:

> This operation conflicts with another pending operation on this transaction. The operation failed.

Stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.RunParser(BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinuedOnSuccess(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)
```

When I debug the code and I skip over the code that executes the `SET XACT_ABORT ON` statement, then it suddenly works and keeps working.

When I restore the database and try again I get the error again.

The bulk insert just inserts one record in a table.

Does anyone has an idea what can be causing the problem?

Comment: How certain are you that it keeps working? Maybe you are not noticing the error with XACT_ABORT OFF. Attach profiler, enable the error event and make 100% there are no errors.

Comment: @usr

I'm sure because the action is triggered from a gui.When it works data is returned as expected otherwise nothing is returned.

Comment: So what if data is partially inserted and errors are suppressed? SqlBulkCopy supports batches. In any case you need to post the relevant code.

Comment: I've added the code where the exception occurs and a stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does "SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints" in your bulk copy options fix the problem?  In my case the table I was doing the bulk copy to had a foreign key to a table I was inserting a record to within the same transaction.  If that is your case, you may want to have your bulk copy table not check for existing records in the foreign key going to the other table.

Comment: Thanks for the response.It helped to apply a workaround.
Temporarely disabling a foreign key constraint solves the problem.
Still strange because in the end nothing is inserted in the column and null is allowed.

Comment: I had the same exact issue with the same setup: Bulk inserting to a table with a nullable column with a FK. Since I wasn't getting any information from the error message, I found that CheckConstraints was false by default. Setting to true solved the problem. No need to drop and recreate the constraint, especially if multiple threads/processes are bulk inserting into the same table. HTH someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer, setting SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints fixed it for me.

```vb
        Dim copyOptions As SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints 

        Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(xcn.Connection, copyOptions, trans)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = MainTable
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
        End Using
```